# Alternative elementary method to find maximum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose we have to solve the below problem. 
For real $a,b,c,abc \neq0$ find maximum of $\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

I do like this: $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0 \implies 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq 2(ab+ac+bc)\\\div (a^2+b^2+c^2) \\
1\geq \frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\implies \max\{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\}=1$$ 
now; my question.
(First) Is there any other (suitable for high school) way to find solution ?

(Second) Is there generality for more variables? for example $$\max\{\frac{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \}=?$$

Comment: To conclude $max\{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\}=1$ you have to prove that $1$ is obtained (yes, it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Second) For $n$ non-zero (not all zero) reals $\;a_1, \dots, a_n,\;$ we can proceed analogously:

$$0\leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a_i-a_j)^2 = 2(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2 - 4\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_ia_j,$$
from where
$$\frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_ia_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2}\leq\frac{n-1}{2}.$$
Consequently is 
$$\max{\frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_ia_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2}}\leq \frac{n-1}{2}.$$ The value  $\;\frac{n-1}{2}\;$ is obtained if all terms $a_i$ are equal.

If the high school students have difficulties to understand due to the formalism, you can do it for a reasonable $n.$

(First) Mathematical induction is suitable (though not easy) at high school level.